# How to handle 16-bit characteristics in Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I've been searching for days for the answer to this question.

I'm writing an Android app to interface with a Bluetooth Low Energy device. I have the device's 128-bit Service ID UUID, and several 16-bit Characteristic IDs. How do I handle these 16-bit values in software? Am I supposed to extend them to 128 bits by combining them with the default BLE UUID of `0000SSSS-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`(where the 'SSSS' is the 16-bit characteristic ID value)? If not that, what?

I can't find any documentation on this, and I can't figure it out by looking at the sample app provided with the [`RxAndroidBle` library](https://polidea.github.io/RxAndroidBle/) that I'm trying to use.

Note this is a unique device and I'm not concerned with compatibility with other devices of its type, because there aren't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a full 128-bit `UUID` of your 16-bit shortened `UUID`.

For instance a Weight Characteristic has a 16-bit `UUID` of `2A9D` which corresponds to `UUID.fromString("00002A9D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")`.